# Denseness of vector space $V=C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V=C^1[0,1]$, $X=( C[0,1],||  ||_\infty )$ and $Y=( C[0,1],||  ||_2 )$. Then  $V$ is

1. dense in $X$ but not in $Y$
2. dense in $Y$ but not in $X$
3. dense in both $X$ and $Y$
4. neither dense in $X$ nor dense in $Y$.

I know that option 3 is true as by Weirstrass approximation theorem, every $f$ in $X$ or $Y$ can be approximated by some polynomial $g$ in $V$ s.t. for every $\epsilon>0$, $|f-g|<\epsilon$. But is it true that the two different norms wouldn't be affecting the result? Kindly correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weierstrass approximation theorem states that every function in $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ can be **uniformly** approximated by a sequence of polynomials. Hence, $V$ is dense in $X$.

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$, one has: $$\|f\|_2^2=\int_{0}^1|f(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t\leqslant\int_0^1\|f\|_{\infty}^2=\|f\|_{\infty}^2.$$
Hence, one has: $$\|f\|_2\leqslant\|f\|_{\infty}.$$
If a sequence converges in $X$, it will converges in $Y$.

Comment: oh!! thanks again C.Falcon..great work.

Comment: My pleasure. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that you have $\|f\|_{2} \le \| f \|_{\infty} \mu ([0,1]) = \| f \|_{\infty} $.

Thus if the approximation works with ${\infty}$-norm it works with the $2$-norm (this remains true as long as the underlying set has finite measure). 
Consequently here any subset that is dense with respect ${\infty}$-norm is also dense with respect to $2$-norm.

The converse is not necessarily true. For an example consider the subset of continuous functions that have $f(0)= f(1) =0$. This is dense in the $2$-norm but not in the $\infty$-norm.